# How to know current image bands?

Tags: fixed-wing, dji-phantom

I work with sets of images from sensors such as:

- DJI P4 Multispectral
- DJI P4 PRO
- MicaSense RedEdge-MX
- MicaSense RedEdge-P

Then I extract attributes from the images. For this, I need to know the current band configuration for each orthomosaic I am working on.
Is there a way to know current band configuration? I use Agisoft Metashape for image processing and QGIS for analysis.

Does the Raster Calculator from Metashape tells the current band configuration?
What about the Camera Calibration on Metashape? If you change the band configuration there, is it reflected in the Raster Calculator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) (freeware).  Run your images against ExifTool and check the Band Name in EXIF tools.  My REd Edge mx image IMG_0031_.tif shows it as a blue band, for example.

With respect to the Phantom 4 images that is an RGB image so unless you are using software to exploit and reassemble your image bands you can expect band 1 to be red and band 2 to be green...

Exif Tool should help you identify the bands of the DJI multispectral but typically you can expect band 4 to be the IR image.  My Parrot Sequoia images come in named bands is that not the case with the Red Edge?  Either way, again, EXIF Tool.

Comment: Hi, I have heard about this option before and decided to give it a try again. It does not show current band configuration unfortunately. Maybe I am missing a 'flag' that will do so? I tried with an orthomosaic generated from MicaSense RedEdge-P.

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  No, I am not referring to running ExifTool on a mosaic Agisoft generated from RedEdge images, I am talking about using EXIFTool to identify which of the images from the camera are which bands.  By default Agisoft will output a mosaic in the same band order as the input files.  See here:  https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=11904.0 and here: https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=11189.0  and then, Metashape will write a log file if that option was checked in the Preferences.  Do you have access to the original Metashape project?

Comment: I guess an option would be to manually inspect band 1 (red) against a known red image from the camera to confirm which band is which.  Do the same for the other bands.

Comment: And finally, repost this question at GIS stack exchange with the unmanned and photogrammetry tags for a more focused audience.

Comment: Yes, I have access to the Metashape project.